# Not square rotation matrix with prcmp R

Tags: r, pca

I was performing a principal component analysis, using a dataframe that contains 247 predictors (columns) and 96 individuals (rows). All of the predictors are numeric and there are not missing values (I imputed the dataframe with mice package).

The pca is working well. However, when I tried to access to the loading matrix (rotation), I realized that it is not a square matrix. I guess it should be a 247 x 247 matrix (due to the fact I have 247 variables). However, the matrix has 247 rows (all my variables) and 96 columns (principal components). Why does not compute all the principal components?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The number of principal components is only equal to the number of columns if the number of columns is less than the number of rows and if no combination of the columns is perfectly correlated. You have many more columns than rows so the maximum number of components is equal to the number of rows or less.

Comment: Greetings! Typically it is recommended to provide a minimally reproducible dataset with your question. One way of achieving this is by using the `dput` command. You can check out how to do this at this video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg